# How to validate input on Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm using [Tag Manager](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager) to get some tags from user on `aspx` webform.
The existed documentation is poor and I can't do my job.
This is the interface that the user enters a phone number and after press `enter` or `tab` key (predefined in `tagmanager.js`), the tag automatically created and show the numbers in tag style:
[image]
I could limit the user input to numbers only by some javascript coding but failed to define criteria that the user can only enter the value in `09\d{9}$` format.
However, I put an `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` for the input but it works only on blur or submits.

This is the code I try to:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="tagBuilder.aspx.cs" Inherits="Customers_Gym.User.tagBuilder" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Tag Builder Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/assets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/assets/bootstrap-extend.css">
    <link href="css/tagmanager.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br />
                    <input id="txtTag" type="text" runat="server" name="tagsk" 
                        placeholder="Phone Numbers" class="input-medium tm-input tm-input-success tm-input-typeahead form-control" 
                        maxlength="11" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);">
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="redError" ID="regval3"
                        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Incorrect intput"
                        ValidationExpression="09\d{9}$"
                        ControlToValidate="txtTag"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" runat="server" value="click to submit form" onserverclick="btn_ServerClick" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tagmanager.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>

        var tagApi = jQuery(".tm-input.tm-input-typeahead").tagsManager({
            prefilled: [<%=test%>],
            hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagAhil',
            validator: null
        });
        jQuery(".tm-input.tm-input-typeahead").typeahead(null, {
            name: 'countries',
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: countries.ttAdapter()
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, d) {
            tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", d.name);
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        function IsNumeric(e) {
            var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
            return ret;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In tag Manager document, there is a property names  `validator: null`and the only explanation for it is:

> **validator** An optional callback function to validate the user input. Takes the tag string as input, and must return true or false. Default: null (no validation function used).

There isn't any example so I can't find out how to add regex or criteria for the tag manager input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time try and error, I could use get help from `Tag Manager Events` and `Tag Manager API Methods`. there are some events that you can find out what events fires now and when do you want to do something.
I first try `tm:pushed` event [when a new tag is pushed], to alert if a tag added by this code:

```
jQuery(".tm-input").on('tm:pushed', function(e, tag) {
  alert(tag + " was pushed!");
});
```

then I try to add a validator function to valid input tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function phoneNumber(d) {
       var pattern = /09\d{9}$/;
       if ((pattern.test(d))) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
     }
 </script>
```

after that I try to send alert if input is not validate!

```
tagApi.on('tm:pushed', function(e, tag) {
   if (!phoneNumber(tag)) {
       alert(tag + " is not correct phone number");
   }
});
```

Here I stuck to how to prevent pushing tag if the condition is false, but I noticed there is a method that exists in the documentation for removing the last added tag called `tagsManager('popTag');`.
Finally, I change the code as follows to achieve limit user input to correct format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Tag Builder Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/assets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/assets/bootstrap-extend.css">
    <link href="css/tagmanager.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br />
                    <input id="txtTag" type="text" runat="server" name="tagsk" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);"
                        placeholder="Phone Numbers" class="input-medium tm-input tm-input-success tm-input-typeahead form-control" 
                        maxlength="11" >
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="redError" ID="regval3"
                        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Incorrect input"
                        ValidationExpression="09\d{9}$"
                        ControlToValidate="txtTag"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" runat="server" value="click to submit form" onserverclick="btn_ServerClick" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tagmanager.js"></script>
    <script>
        var tagApi = jQuery(".tm-input.tm-input-typeahead").tagsManager({
            prefilled: [<%=test%>],
            hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagAhil',
            validator: null
        });
        tagApi.on('tm:pushed', function(e, tag) {
            if (!phoneNumber(tag)) {
                alert(tag + " is not correct phone number");
                tagApi.tagsManager('popTag');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function phoneNumber(d) {
            var pattern = /09\d{9}$/;
            if ((pattern.test(d))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        function IsNumeric(e) {
            var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
            return ret;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thus, If a user input an incorrect phone number format, the incorrect input will remove immediately.